# Spring Integration DSL Scatter-Gatherer: Why isn't applySequence(true) the default?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

All the examples I've seen of the Spring Integration DSL Scatter-Gatherer explicitly set the `.applySequence(true)` on the scatterer.

E.g. like this:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow helloFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(Http.inboundChannelAdapter("hello").get())
            .scatterGather(s -> s
                    .applySequence(true)
                    .recipientFlow(f -> f.handle((m, h) -> 33))
                    .recipientFlow(f -> f.handle((m, h) -> 444))
            )
            .split()
            .log()
            .get();
}
```

If I omit `.applySequence(true)` I get

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Null correlation not allowed.  Maybe the CorrelationStrategy is failing?
```

Why is the sequence needed in this case ?
If it needed in so many cases, why isn't `.applySequence(true)` just the default with the option of explicitly setting it to false if desired for some reason ? And when would you explicitly want it to be set to false ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scatterer part of this component is fully based on the Recipient List Router which comes with `false` for that option by default. So, for consistency and runtime optimization we keep it false in scatter-gather as well: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/message-routing.html#router-implementations-recipientlistrouter. In real world it is really rear case when gathered messages come back with those generated sequence details headers. Typically the gatherer is configured to custom correlation and release strategies. It is more demo and samples feature to `applySequence` to be honest. Plus, don’t forget the message immutability and with option we enforce the framework to create a new message to add sequence details headers.

Comment: I'm not sure if we are misusing scatter-gather then... But we often have the following use case: 
1) Our flow gets started by a trigger (e.g. REST call)
2) We use a scatter-gather to concurrently fetch data from multiple sources (scatter) and merge the responses together (gather).

In those cases we are always working with "applySequence".

Comment: Sure! But wouldn’t it be better to have a static release strategy since you know how many result you are waiting for in aggregator ?

Comment: That link redirects me to ../html/channel.html#channel-configuration-pubsubchannel where I read "If you provide a resequencer or aggregator downstream from a PublishSubscribeChannel, you can set the 'apply-sequence' property on the channel to true. Doing so indicates that the channel should set the sequence-size and sequence-number message headers as well as the correlation ID prior to passing along the messages." However, the scatter gather pattern explicitly expects an aggregator, so it would make a lot of sense to set applySequence to true by default for the scatter gather, no ?

Comment: I don't understand the runtime optimization argument (it's just a boolean) and the consistency argument is weak IMO compared to the expected behavior of a gatherer/aggregator inside scatter-gather. We're using it in an enterprise setting and relying on the sequence headers every time so far.

Comment: As you see the doc says "you can", but not "must". You probably missed my point that `applySequence=true` enforce the framework to create a new message instance with those extra sequence details headers. That's that optimization part for which we don't want to hear back that there is a pure performance by default. If you really want to always rely on the `applySequence=true`, you can write your own DSL extension and use it everywhere you need in your code: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/dsl.html#java-dsl-extensions.